# How to minimize the large number of Math in C#?

Tags: c#, math

[image]


I wrote here such code:

```
Double x = 3.74 * Math.Pow(10.0, -2);
Double y = -0.825;
Double z = 0.16 * Math.Pow(10.0, 2);
Double v;

v = 1 + Math.Pow(Math.Sin, 2)(x + y) / Math.Abs(x - 2*y/1 + Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2)) * Math.Pow(x, Math.Abs(y)) + Math.Pow(Math.Cos, 2)*(Math.Atan * 1/z);

Console.WriteLine(v);

Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

But I got the message from compiler that this solution is used too much Math.

P.S. I am use SharpDevelop becauseit is lightweight. I myself learn programming, because I want to change jobs.

Comment: `"But I got the message that this solution is used too much Math."` - I have no idea what that means.

Comment: "But I got the message that this solution is used too much Math." What? Got that message from what/who?

Comment: From your teacher, co-worker, boss?  Surely not the compiler.

Comment: That code wont even compile. `Math.Sin`, `Math.Cos`, and `Math.Atan` are methods, not properties

Comment: one way to make your code look better is to break your god function into smaller pieces. for example calculate numerator and denominator separately and in another line divide them.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: You can also do a `using static System.Math` in C# 6 so you you don't have to use the class name everyhwere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You solve problems like this by breaking them up into easy to understand parts.  I make zero guarantee that I've got this right, but I wanted to demonstrate the technique for you:

```
Double numerator= 1 + Math.Sin(x + y) * Math.Sin(x + y);
Double denominator = Math.Abs(x - ((2 * y) / (1 + (x*x)*(y*y))));

Double firstTerm = (numerator / denominator) * Math.Pow(x, Math.Abs(y));
Double secondTerm = Math.Cos(Math.Atan(1/z) * Math.Cos(Math.Atan(1/z);

Double finalAnswer = firstTerm + secondTerm;
```

Note the number of parenthesis on the second line - this is a sign that I should have broke this into another term as it has become too complex.

Comment: You could skip some unnecessary parenthesis in second line, like so:
    `Math.Abs(x - (2 * y / (1 + x * x * y * y)));`

Comment: I could, but I was making it obvious to the reader than I was doing x^2 and y^2.